# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null error in java while generating invoice number from oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to generate invoice no automatically and had created table called Product at Oracle sql db and when i checked from backend table's max value is 103 but when i am doing from this code i am getting error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Table desc is

```
ID NUMBER(4),  
MANUF_NAME VARCHAR2(20)
```

and it has already 3 records and highest ID number is 103 and now i have to get 104 but not getting

```
public void InvoiceNo ()
{
    try {
        connection2database();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select MAX(ID) from PRODUCT");

        if (rs.next())  
        {
            int invoicenumber = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1))+1;
            jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(invoicenumber));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, Ex.toString());
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you try using  rs.getInt(1) instead of rs.getString(1). Also instead of adding 1 in java  while getting your result from DB do +1 and directly use the value.

Comment: in jlabel2, I have to get max value of table +1, According to this requirement only, the above code is

Comment: Yes, so if you "select MAX(ID)+1 from PRODUCT" that will suffice and you wont have to add +1 in java.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the same table? That you're not in the wrong schema, server or anything. It sounds like you're accessing an empty table.

Comment: No.. Table is filled with records and it's max value is 103. And also if i tried with one specific table named emp in my database, I am getting correct output with above code but apart from that table this code is not working on other tables and getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void InvoiceNo ()
{
    try {
        connection2database();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        /* While getting value from DB do +1*/
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select MAX(ID)+1 from PRODUCT");

        if (rs.next())  
        {           
            jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1)));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, Ex.toString());
        }
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried with your suggestion but got output as 0